# Practicality and security when using SQLite for my website database?

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am building a website for the company I work for, for which the front-end has been done. Currently the site populates itself from information read off a JSON file.

I will be leaving this job soon, and want to leave the site so that other employees will be able to update it without needing to know how to read and write JSON data properly. So I am writing a VERY simple site to do the updates (list the projects currently on the live site, lets users add a project, delete a project or reorder projects.) The data is all text, and I am doing some basic sanitizing in JS before calling the server to write. What's more, I am using [.htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess) to require employees to log in to even get to this part of the site.

So now I am to the point where I need an actually database to write to. As our website is run off of an OSX server, we already had SQLite3 installed. It seemed from what I read here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql) that SQLite works just fine as a live database, as long as I dont need UN/PW access, or the need to scale up to 100k+ hits. (We are a small company - we will be getting 2-3 hits a day).

I starting setting up a PHP page to connect to the database and write to it, and after a silent failure, realized that the .DB file needed RW access for group in order for the website to access it. This would mean a chmod to at least 444, if not 777, for the db and the directory holding it (I assume). I asked my boss, who handles server admin, about setting this up, and he said he was not comfortable doing this. And while I understand his concern, I am not sure what else I am supposed to do. Without RW access on the file, I don't know any other means to make this work.

So what are my options? Should I abandon SQLite and just install MySQL? And if I do stick with SQLite, what are best practices for security? Is there some accepted best way to set it up the batabase / encrypt data / hide the database?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the concern with giving RW access to the file?

Comment: My boss is concerned that any ability to write to the file by group (in this case, www) would allow people to compromise our system somehow. I don't know anything about security, so I can't argue the point, and don't know that there is not some way to use this file to inject some sort of nastiness on to our server if someone so desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may be confusing here is *UNIX/Linux file permissions* with *web accessibility*.

In *NIX, every file belongs to an owner and a group. Every process on the machine, including the user on a terminal, is running under a user which belongs to a group (or groups). *That* is what file permissions are about. They control which process can access which files. The user may have direct permissions for a file (user permissions), indirect permissions through his group membership or, if nothing else, *other* permissions.

This all has nothing to do with a web user. The *web server* is a process listening to incoming HTTP requests on port 80 (or elsewhere). It then decides how to respond to these requests. At no point does this kind of *do-I-respond-or-don't-I* have anything to do with file permissions. The web server has its own rules for which requests to *allow* and which to *deny*, which have nothing to do with file permissions.

If the web server is trying to access some file on disk, *then* file permissions play a role. The web server is running as some user belonging to some group, typically `www-data`. That means the web server can read, write or execute files that it has permissions to. If the web server does not have read permissions for a file, it won't be able to serve it. But just because the web server has write permissions to a file does not mean in any way that a website visitor can write to that file in any way, because the web server won't let them. The web server serves web request, it doesn't offer direct file access to random users.

The typical setup is that the web server is running as `www-data`. An incoming request causes the web server to start a PHP script, which also runs as child process with `www-data` permissions. That PHP process reads or writes files; it can only read and write files with the permissions of `www-data` and *you* control what the script reads or writes.

If you want to use a SQLite database, something will have to have permissions to that file. It's true that you typically want to separate permissions as much as possible. But in this case you need to give the `www-data` user (or whatever your PHP is running as) permissions to that file. So what? That's not a security flaw per se. The worst thing that could happen is that an attacker who gets permissions of `www-data` will be able to write to the database. But before that he'll have to have circumvented a whole lot of other security mechanisms, so that should be the least of your worries.

Comment: The last point is the most important one - if an attacker has escalated privileges to the point where file permissions on your SQLite file are an issue, your servers is almost certainly already compromised to the point it should be shut down. Whether you use SQLite or MySQL in this case is probably irrelevant from a security point of view.

Comment: This is essentially what I was going to say. Move the DB file outside the document root and do `chmod 660 <file> && chgrp www-data <file>`. That way, people should not be able to just download the entire DB, passwords and all, unless they find a local file inclusion vulnerability (as in http://eng.xakep.ru/link/50643/). Of course, using a separate DB server such as MySQL would allow you to use the `allow_url_include` and `open_basedir` INI settings for defense in depth.

Comment: I understand most of this, and what is still greek to me on this whole process I will research more. But for now this lets me know enough to help my boss make an informed decision. Thanks!

Comment: @DrHall UNIX permissions are ingeniously simple, so simple that it's hard to wrap your head around them. Every process has an associated user and group(s), every file has different r/w/x permissions per user/group/other. That's it, really. Just remember that website visitors are none of these.